# Make the navigation links below in the login form

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

Im trying to create a navigation which has a login form and  below login form is the menu links.

I want these two in my navigation. But the problem is that the output has only given me is one horizontal. And the menu links are not below in the login form.

I want the menu links below the login form. But it's giving me a wrong output

CSS:

```
.nav-link {
    font-size: 18px !important;
    text-transform: uppercase !important;
    font-weight: 600 !important;
}
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: #ffff !important;

 }

 #search { margin: auto; }
 body {
     overflow-x: hidden;
 }
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, 
    maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title></title>
    <!-- favicon -->
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
    <!-- /favicon -->
    <link href="/realcss/bootstrap-4.1.3.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/realcss/flag-icon.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/realcss/fontawesome-all-5.3.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/layout.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">      
</head>
<body>

    <!-- navigation.tpl -->
    <header>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light fixed-top bg-dark border-bottom" style="float: right;">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="logo" src="/images/logo/M.png" style="max-width: 400px;
        max-height: 64px;" alt=""></a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarCollapse">
                <div id="search">
                    <form class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                        <div class="col-auto pl-0">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
                                </div>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Email Address">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-auto pl-0">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></div>
                                </div>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroup" placeholder="Password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-auto pl-0 pr-0">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Login</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <ul class="navbar-nav d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <li id="li-home" class="nav-item active">
                        <a id="link-home" class="nav-link" href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="li-about" class="nav-item">
                        <a id="link-about" class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="li-team" class="nav-item">
                        <a id="link-team" class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="li-news" class="nav-item">
                        <a id="link-news" class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="li-contact" class="nav-item">
                        <a id="link-contact" class="nav-link" href="{{ route('promotion') }}">Promotion</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following CSS:

```
 .navbar-expand-md .navbar-collapse{
     flex-direction:column;  
 }
```

### [Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mirohristov/mwLk9v2t/2/)

Comment: Thank you very much. but can i ask what if i want it to float in right and not in center? i did try to remove the justify content center but stll in center

Comment: Because the element is `flex`, you need `.navbar-collapse {align-items: flex-end !important;}`. Also set the margin to 0 on the `#search`. [See this](https://jsfiddle.net/mirohristov/mwLk9v2t/8/)